# Dealing with unmanaged memory in c#

Tags: c#, c++, void-pointers, native-code, unmanaged-memory

I am using native C++ dll in c#, like this:

C++ functions:

```
poly* f1(/*some input data*/);
double* f2(poly* p);
```

In c#, I am doing:

(This is done using unsafe and fixed blocks appropriately, So don't worry about that)

```
void* ptr  = f1(/*input data*/);
double[] result = f2(ptr);
```

Now If I print data from `f2`, I get some data corrupted, garbage values. And some values are correct. I want to know, Is it due to saving that in void pointer `ptr`? Or is that fine and reason is something else?

Comment: What does the f2 declaration look like? What kind of data is passed in and out of it?

Comment: You cannot safely call these functions from C++ code either, there's a very serious memory management problem.  It doesn't get better when you try to do it from C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the marshaller can't automatically convert double* to double[], because it has no idea how long the array is, and there could be a lot of other issues. You have to give us ideally at least the header file in C++, the declaration of your DllImported extern method in C# and then we can dig deeper into this :)